# Timer trouble . .

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, kinect

I'm trying to make a button in wpf vs 2010 that when clicked will periodically perform an action , I've looked at a tonne of different similar problems on this and other sites but the problem is I'm trying to call a function which takes screenshots from a kinect ,  can get a timer to work but it keeps freezing so rather than 10 different screenshots with 2.5 second intervals I'm gettin the same screenshot again and again , any help much appreciated.
At the moment I'm using a checkbox instead of a button as per some tips I found on here.

```
    private void checkBox1_Checked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        // Begin timing
        stopwatch.Start();

        // Do something
        for (int i = 0; i < 60000; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3);
        }

        // Stop timing
        stopwatch.Stop();

        take_motions();
    }
```

Comment: The code you've posted here is just timing how long it takes to Sleep 60k times at roughly ~10ms a pop; thread sleep has a granularity of about 10 ms, plus or minus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a specialized timer class in WPF that avoids any UI cross threading issues as it runs in the UI thread. It's the [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) class:

```
private DispatcherTimer timer;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5) };
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // take screenshot here
}

private void checkBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Start();
}

private void checkBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code you are blocking the main application thread. That would explain why you are getting the same screenshot over and over again.

What you need to do is start the timer in a background thread and then form **that thread** send an event to the main application to take a screenshot. This will then allow the application to carry on working.

To do this you should use one of the `Timer` classes available. They each work slightly differently, but all should allow you to specify a method to be called on each tick of the timer.

You will need to send an event back to the UI to avoid cross threading issues.

Answer (score 1):

You should use timer and run `take_motions();` in a separate thread:

```
aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

// Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

// Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
aTimer.Interval = 2000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;

private void checkBox1_Checked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //here call timer start or stop
}

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
   {
     take_motions();
   });
}
```